# Do- while loop suggestion needed

Tags: powershell

I want to print all the numbers from 1 through 50 and show it in the screen.

The next step is I want to sum up all the numbers and store the value into a variable to show it on the screen, but cannot understand how to do this.

I have done the following, can you suggest me how I can do the next step?

```
$i=1
do 
{ 
    write-host "The numbers   : $i"
    $i++
}
while ($i -le 50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `$sum` variable and add the value of `$i` to it everytime the loop runs:

```
$sum = 0
$i = 1
do 
{
    $sum += $i
    write-host "The numbers   : $i"
    $i++
}
while ($i -le 50)
Write-Host "The total sum is : $sum"
```

---

You could also generate all the numbers in advance with the `..` range operator:

```
$AllTheNumbers = 1..50 
$AllTheNumbers |ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "The number: $_"
}
```

And calculate the sum with `Measure-Object`:

```
$Sum = ($AllTheNumbers |Measure-Object -Sum).Sum

Write-Host "Sum: $Sum"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following one line code to do your work

```
1..50 | % -b {$sum=0} -p {$sum+=$_; $_} -e {"The total sum is: $sum"};
```